# Вставка элементов в список и перенумерация полученного списка

Tags: python

Есть список:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,2]
```

и нужно чтобы последнее число вставало перед числом 2, числа после перенумеровывались, и в итоге получался список

```
х=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Список может быть и больше, и последнее число может быть разным. Но всегда оно должно вставляться в список на своё место по порядку!

Пытался идти несколькими способами:

1. создавал другой список и сравнивал их
2. пытался искать одинаковые числа
3. пытался писать условия

но чего-то не то...

как правильно это сделать по python-ски?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `print(list(range(1, len(x)+1)))`

Comment: судя то тексту вопроса, на результате не скажутся ни числа исходного листа, ни значение добавляемого числа

Answer (score 2):

Для вставки числа в нужную позицию используйте insert:

```
l = list(range(3))
print(l)
# [0, 1, 2]

l.insert(0, 100)
print(l)
# [100, 0, 1, 2]

l.insert(-1, 200)
print(l)
# [100, 0, 1, 200, 2]
```

---

Требование «перенумеровывать» сводит задачу к формированию нового списка, никак не зависящего от вставляемого значения:

```
l[:] = range(1, len(l)+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Поигрался немного и вот что получилось!
Вроде всё работает!

```
list = [1,2,3,4,6]
list.sort()
newlist=[]
for i in list:
    if i in newlist:
        bool=True
        while bool:
            if newlist:
                i+=1
                bool=True
            else:
                newlist.append(i)
                bool=False
    else:
        newlist.append(i)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом (ссылка `править`)

Comment: В питоне у списка нет функции `Contains` и тем более `Conains`. Наличие элемента в списке проверяется через оператор `in`: `if i in new_list`

Comment: у меня python стоит в Dynamo, и такая функция есть!

Comment: @CrazyElf поправил!!!

Answer (score 0):

Автоматически рассортировать и убрать дубли

```
list(set(x))
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять более распространенные ответы.

Comment: Задача не про это )